# deploy war on amazon EC2

Tags: grails, amazon-ec2

When I deploy a Grails application using RDS I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Check whether database is running or not.

Comment: Yes , I have checked and war able to create database. But it still throwing this error